# Will a UIViewController subclass also affect my UITableViewControllers?

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, subclass

I need to add a common method to all my view controllers no matter what type they are.  I notice though that some of my viewcontrollers inherit from UIViewController and some from UITableViewControllers.

How do I write a subclass that can be used for both?

Comment: Is there some way to override, lets say, viewDidLoad method for both UITableViewController and UIViewController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UITableViewController inherits from UIViewController, so if you want to be able to call your custom method from both, you can write a category on UIViewController and then call methods from that category in any subclass of either UIViewController or UITableViewController. Here's a link to Apple's docs on categories and extensions. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html

Comment: above link is broken. Instead, use this... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW2

Answer (score 1):

if you add a category to `UIViewController`, you will be able to call those methods on `UITableViewController` subclasses, as `UITableViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`